# PyInstaller does not include the kivy.garden.mapview package.What is the workaround?

Tags: python, package, kivy, site-packages

- Python Version: 3.6.7(Anaconda Environment)
- Kivy Version: 1.10.1

So I installed mapview with the command `garden install mapview` and my python file easily detects it and runs it.But when I make exe with PyInstaller it showed the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named garden.mapview`

I somehow found a solution to install all garden things by adding `--kivy` in the end.

I used matplotlib of garden with command `garden install matplotlib --kivy` and it works after making exe with PyInstaller using method shown here [kivy Page for making exe](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html)

But when I installed mapview with the command `garden install mapview --kivy` which makes it appear in site-packages of my Anaconda Environment, it shows following error- `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mapview.types'`

So it seems like adding `--kivy` improved the situation but didn't completely solved it.
**So how to do it?** *Any workaounds will also be appreciated*.

For more clarity mapview's directory(in site-packages of my environment) contains another mapview folder which have a file types.py

I know it will be a bad practice but **can I copy the whole code of mapview package line by line and paste it in my python file and use it's functions and classes directly?** *and yes by editing lines like import blah from blah.*

Comment: The [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.garden.html#packaging) says to use `garden install --app package`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson garden install --app package does not work either.